# How can I dynamically create a playlist for a chromeless player?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

My workspace is here:http://jsfiddle.net/WBFa4/89/
I am trying to detect the end of a video to load the next video.The onStateChange event is never fired.What might be the issue?

```
swfobject.embedSWF
 (
    'http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1&version=3',
    'ytplayer_div1',
'425',
'344',
'8',
null,
null,
{
    allowScriptAccess: 'always',
            allowFullScreen: 'true'
},
{
    id: 'ytplayer_object'
}
);
onYouTubePlayerReady = function() {
var ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytplayer_object");
addEventListener("onStateChange","handlestatechange");  
ytplayer.loadVideoById("V2AshX3tfHU", 5, "large");
}
function handlestatechange(state) {
 if(state==0) {
    ytplayer.loadVideoById("bHQqvYy5KYo");
 }
}
```